# Getting JMSException connecting to IBM MQ from Java client

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

We are trying to connect to IBM MQ from a Java client. We have generated `.bindings` for JNDI context using the JMSAdmin utility. When connecting to IBM MQ we are getting following exception:

```
ERR fmbaJMS JMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager '<queue manager name>' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'null'
```

Host name parameter sent is null while `.bindings` file correctly have

```
mq/RefAddr/30/Content=localhost(51410)
mq/RefAddr/30/Type=CRSHOSTS
```

Entries pointing to localhost and port 51410.

Comment: I think we'd need to see more code. The file `.bindings` you refer to is read by the JVM's `RefFSContextFactory` JNDI provider, which has to be initialized in a particular way.

Answer (score 2):

Your .bindings file does not look right.  What was the JMSAdmin command you used to create it?

> MQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'bt.qm.ccxp0'

Is that your queue manager name or QCF?  Note: As per the IBM Best Practises, queue manager names should be in uppercase.

To define a QCF (Queue Connection Factory), you would do:

```
DEFINE QCF(myQCF) QMANAGER(MQA1) CHANNEL(TEST.CHL) HOSTNAME(127.0.0.1) PORT(1414) TRANSPORT(CLIENT) FAILIFQUIESCE(YES)
```

To define a JMS queue, you would do:

```
DEFINE Q(mqs.dev.test.q) QUEUE(TEST.Q1) QMANAGER(MQA1) TARGCLIENT(JMS) FAILIFQUIESCE(YES)
```

Then in your code, you would do the following to load the objects from the MQ JNDI:

```
Hashtable<String,String> env = new Hashtable<String,String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "file:/C:/JNDI-Directory");

Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);

QueueConnectionFactory cf = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("myQCF");
Queue q = (Queue) ctx.lookup("mqs.dev.test.q");
```

Comment: Here hostname sent is "null" ... (ERR fmbaJMS JMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'bt.qm.ccxp0' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'null' ) ... Could it be problem

Comment: As I said above: What was the JMSAdmin command you used to create it?

Comment: java -Djava.library.path=$MQ_JAVA_LIB_PATH -DMQJMS_LOG_DIR=$MQ_JAVA_DATA_PATH/log -DMQJMS_TRACE_DIR=$MQ_JAVA_DATA_PATH/trace -DMQJMS_INSTALL_PATH=$MQ_JAVA_INSTALL_P
ATH com.ibm.mq.jms.admin.JMSAdmin <$FILE

$FILE is where JMSAdmin commands are placed

Comment: What was in `$FILE`?

Comment: You gave us the command to run the JMSAdmin tool.  I want to see the JMSAdmin commands that the JMSAdmin tool processed.  As JoshMc said, what is in $FILE?

Comment: I could resolve that exception as there was error in generating keydb ... but now we are facing
JMSException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'xxx' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(xxxxx)' ... We are using not providing username password in factory.createQueueConnection call

Comment: Ok.  Now you need to supply a valid UserId & Password on the createQueueConnection() method.  Security is important. Do it right when you are testing and then it will go smoothly when you deploy your app to your production environment.